# Frequency capping with AMPScript Exclusion script

Tags: marketing-cloud, exclusion-script

Our dataextensions might have the same email address with different subscriber keys, and when i send multiple emails a day to different data extension, i am sending multiple emails to those emails addresses. I am trying to avoid sending multiple emails and thinking to use AMPScript in Advanced Exclusion section. Any ideas what that script should be?

Comment: This solution depends on the business logic you need to implement. E.g. should it always be the first email on that day, which should be sent to a particular email address?

Comment: Yes so depends on where the contact is located email should just be sent once with correct content targetting specific geolocation. what I noticed with our data geolocation is not consistent and the same email address can be in 2 different DE with different geolocation info. For example the same email address can be in Canadian and US Data Extensions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using SendLog DE to store the emails for each send - and then have a filtered Data Extension which would give you the emails for a particular day (time period) - then in the Exclusion Script you could use the LookUpRows function to see if there's already 1 or more that match with the email - if count > 0, then Exclusion script shall evaluate to True and the email could be excluded from the send. You may need to figure out an automation to run the Filter Activity and refresh the Filtered DE to always shows the latest SendLog email ids for the specific day.

Comment: Hi there @shibua, thanks for your reply, can you please send me an example script of how it would look like. Thank you!

Comment: Let's say you have the filtered sendlog DE as "TodaysSendDE", and you are capturing the email of the sent subscriber in field "EmailID", then you can use the exclusion script as RowCount(LookUpRows("TodaysSendDE","EmailID",emailaddr)) > 0. This would become true when the filtered DE has 1 or more records with the same email id already sent today - hence it will exclude the current send.